# Mule - How to setup a user defined cron schedule

Tags: mule, mule-component

I looked at the docs for scheduling..
http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Managing+Schedules
http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Quartz+Connector

But I’m missing something..

I want the client to decide on a schulede, eg once a day at 1am or once a week on Sunday at 2am
And then make an http call to a Mule workflow to send the information.

The mule workflow will receive the (cron) schedule in the http request and then use that information to setup the required schedule

In the examples and docs the schedule is always hard coded into the workflow

How can I achieve this?

Thanks for any insight.
  Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use spring properties to pass the cron expression.

```
       <quartz:inbound-endpoint jobName="myServiceJob"
            cronExpression="${file.pollFrequency}" doc:name="Quartz">
            <quartz:event-generator-job />
        </quartz:inbound-endpoint>
```

Note that this way, the polling frequency needs to be passed before the application actually starts. HTH.

Comment: Thanks, can I set file.pollFrequency with a prior http GET into Mule?

Comment: IIRC, quartz is initialised at start up, therefore I don't think it is possible to pass the cron expression at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be to use the Poll message processor. You can either use a fixed frequency scheduler or make use of a cron expression. Moreover, you're also able to make use of watermarks.